# Dart: Iterable<E> vs. List<E>, always use Iterable?

Tags: dart

Dart newbie question.

List is a child class of Iterable, and some list methods return Iterable instead of List, e.g., List's [where method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Iterable/where.html). If we declare a variable as List, we have to call `toList` in many places.

Is it better to always declare our variable as Iterable type instead of List (or any other subtypes), so our code is generic and easy to change? Is there any downside of doing so? This is more like a best practice question.

Edits

After changing some List to Iterable in my codebase, I found Iterable instances have no `add` method. It is used to be *iterated* only, as the name suggests. So obvious.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should declare your variables as the most precise type that provides the functionality and guarantees that you need.

List guarantees efficient length and random access operations, and gives access to functionality like `sort` and `shuffle` which are only efficient when they have access to all the elements from the start. They belong on `List` because if they had been on `Iterable`, every efficient implementation would start by doing `toList` to get a list anyway.

You should think the same way about your code: If you want or expect a list, type it as `List`. If you can do with any collection, use `Iterable` - which usually means that the operations you use can all be implemented by a `for-in` over the elements.
If you are always going to transform an iterable into a list before you use it, you might as well type the variable as `List` to make sure you remember to make the list.

Or, in short, if you don't care whether it's actually a `Set` or `Queue` or `LinkedList` or whether it's unmodifiable or lazy, you can make it an `Iterable`.

(You should still generally only iterate an iterable once - the moment you want to use it twice, it's *likely* that you'd be better off creating a guaranteed non-lazy collection from it - and `List` is the cheapest collection to create).

Comment: Iterable has elementAt() method and it is said that List [] operator is just syntactical sugar for it. Is it true?

Comment: The `List.operator[]` and `List.elementAt` methods are defined to do the same thing, so ... basically, yes. For a list, it is the same thing.

Comment: No noticeable difference. I just made a quick benchmark and ran it on both native and web, and the two approaches are indistinguishable.

Comment: It's noticeable, I run [this](https://gist.github.com/ivanesi/afac1ca148ecd370cb65ef9bdd99d398) with and without `dart2native` compilation

Comment: True, when compiling to an `exe` (`dart compile exe`) I see a difference for [this](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/706ec53a39f57f4fc0133b32d9289c1b) which isn't there when JIT compiled.

Answer (score 22):

A List is an indexable collection of objects with a length.

```
List<E> class
```

An iterable is a collection of values, or "elements", that can be accessed sequentially.

```
Iterable<E> class
```

The elements of the iterable are accessed by getting an Iterator

```
Iterator<E> class
```

Now, as you can see iterable does not have any add method. This is on purpose. We get following benefits from using iterable :

- Using iterator we get a safer access to the list. Prevents accidental overriding of list as we get access to only one item at a time
- Allows to keep the logic of modifying the list inside the class that contains it. Others can safely consume it.
- This forces us to keep all complex operations related to the list inside its defining class

[Note](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/library-tour#iteration) : The Iterable and Iterator classes support for-in loops. Extend (if possible) or implement Iterable whenever you create a class that can provide Iterators for use in for-in loops. Implement Iterator to define the actual iteration ability.

Comment: Can you please answer some questions. (1) In your definition, what's the difference between `collection of objects` and `collection of values/elements`? (2) Can you give an example of this line `The elements of the iterable are accessed by getting an Iterator`? (3) Considering previous line to be true, you also then say `The Iterable and Iterator classes support for-in loops` then what's the role of iterator in 2nd question if Iterable can be accessed using the `for-in`.

Answer (score 7):

A `List` is completely concrete at its inception.  An `Iterable` is a "lazy list", and might even be an infinite list.  Iterables are computed as needed.  They have similar properties, but different realizations.