# Why are Dart's Collections implemented with Iterables by default?

Tags: dart, data-structures, collections

I wonder if there is a reason based on some hidden dependency somewhere — like a specific platform to which they wanted to deploy — that demanded this sort of implementation. Is it to make `List` and `Set` united by a single interface? Or maybe they were basing themselves on a language that was successful with this type of implementation? Or maybe I just can't see an obvious data structure reason for it somewhere?

Some other related questions sometimes also pop in my mind about this model — and that might illustrate pros and cons of the `Iterable` approach —:

- Is this really the most efficient way?
- Couldn't having `List` and `Set` accidentally misstyped into `Iterable`s cause annoying bugs and perfomance downgrades, specially when it comes laziness?
- Couldn't `Map` have been integrated into the `Iterable` model? An `ArrayList` of `MapEntry`s?

  - Would implementing a map with a lazy `Iterable` be possible? Maybe it's bad?

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52345694/4756173) addresses many of the pros and cons of Dart's approach, but it would be beneficial to have an official statement on the why for the choice.

> This question was [first posted to r/dartlang](https://www.reddit.com/r/dartlang/comments/longp5/does_anyone_know_why_darts_collections_are_by/).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question(s). Can you be more specific?

Comment: The TLDR version is, I think: why is the extra layer of `Iterable` necessary, when it comes to `List` and `Set`? If it isn't necessary, but is better design, could you please briefly demonstrate why?

Comment: What extra layer of `Iterable`? The `List` and `Set` interfaces *implements* `Iterable`, which means they share some common functionality, and can be used in places where you only need an `Iterable`.
Are you talking about why some of the *methods* return `Iterable`, like `map` and `where`? In that case, it's because being lazy can be an advantage. You can build some things more efficiently by combining lazy operations than by combining eager ones. Say `list.where((x) => test).first` only need to compute `test` until it finds an element which returns true, unlike if `where` was eager.

Comment: What I was trying to say is: what is the intention behind unifying `List` and `Set` with an `Iterable` *exactly*? Because, for example, those objects could be stand alones. And, if the intention was to unify them with a common interface, why not also unify `Map` with it as well? Something like `Iterable<MapEntry>`? Is there a TLDR answer for this last question?

Comment: Having the lazy layer is great in my opinion, but sometimes it can generate unexpected bugs because, by using type inference, sometimes we might end up with `Iterable`s if we are not careful. (I also wanted to suggest that the Dart documentation should have emphasis on that somewhere in an advanced section, because it was an easy thing to spot.) Sometimes I've unified two different types into `Iterable` to make `List` and `Set` compatible with an argument, but that generated unexpected results because laziness was having calculations in different orders.

Comment: Having an `Iterable` supertype of `List`, `Set` (and `Queue`) allows you to use whichever collection you want to *collect* values, then use the same API to consume the values. The `for(...in...)` loop can iterate over any iterable too. The `Future.wait` function can use any iterable. If we had to pick one collection instead, likely `List`, then all callers would have to convert their collections to `List` before using `for(...in...)`.
The reason `Map` is not an iterable is that it's not compatible. `MapEntry` didn't exist from the start, and `Map.forEach` is incompatible with `Iterable`.